# How can I setup Visual C++ 2010 Express to copy some folders during the build process?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm not a regular C++er, so this question might be fairly trivial: Can anybody please tell me what I need to do that during the build process some folders will get copied to the output directory?

My project is currently structured somewhat like this:

```
Projects
    -> ProjectName
        -> .cpp and .h files
        -> Folder1
        -> Folder2
    -> Debug
    -> Release
```

Folder1 and 2 contain some files that are required during runtime, so they need to be shipped with my application - how do I get those into Debug/Release while building the project? Or is there any other recommended method to deal with such situations?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e85wte0k(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the projects properties, use build events, and on the command line enter the equivalent command codes to copy the files.